# Alignment issue for textview in android

Tags: android, layout, textview, alignment

I am trying to get the text "Your token is run out, please reconnect" little up just below the icon and title of "facebook" and "twitter" but there is lot of gap between them. I tried all possible ways but not sure where m missing. Below is my code n screenshot.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/facebook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="Facebook"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/facebook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingRight="15dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/ok" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tokentextfacebook"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/facebook"   
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Your token is run out. Please reconnect"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:gravity="left"
                />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/facebook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="Twitter"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#4a82ae"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/twitter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingRight="15dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/ok" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tokentexttwitter"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/facebook"   
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Your token is run out. Please reconnect"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:gravity="left"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you noticed that your `ImageView` and `TextView` ID is same `facebook` ?

Comment: Ya...i got that but those are static things, so shouldn't affect alignment...I will correct that...Any reason for not aligning ?

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout`.Its easy for proper alignment of controls.

Answer (score 0):

This design would've been easier to implement with RelativeLayout but never the less you could use negative margin on your TextView to position it correctly.

```
android:layoutMarginTop="-10dp"
```

Comment: Is Negative value recommended ?

Comment: @user45678 It can be a neccessary evil in order to place TextViews correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> android:paddingBottom="30dip"

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/facebook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="Facebook"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/facebook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingRight="15dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/ok" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tokentextfacebook"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/facebook"   
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Your token is run out. Please reconnect"
                        android:paddingBottom="30dip"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:gravity="left"
                />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/facebook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="Twitter"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#4a82ae"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/twitter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingRight="15dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/ok" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tokentexttwitter"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/facebook"   
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Your token is run out. Please reconnect"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                        android:paddingBottom="30dip"
                    android:gravity="left"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probelm iw with your min height criteria at wrong place, use this layout just modifed.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/facebook"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="Facebook"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#444444"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/facebook"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="15dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ok" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tokentextfacebook"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/facebook"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:text="Your token is run out. Please reconnect"
            android:textColor="#444444"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/facebook"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="Twitter"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#4a82ae"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/twitter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="15dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ok" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tokentexttwitter"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/facebook"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:text="Your token is run out. Please reconnect"
            android:textColor="#444444"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It gave horrible result

Comment: its was not properly posted, just edited my answer it works try it out